# quaternion renormalization

Tags: python, symbolic-math, sympy

Edit 1: changed a few portions of the code to hopefully make it runnable code and more understandable. If something is still incorrect please let me know.

Edit 2: just remembered I am doing this in python 2.7 because I am required to. If that causes any issues again please let me know.

I am trying to create 4 symbolic equations that correspond to the 4 elements of a normalized quaternion. The equation is for quaternion multiplication

\$\dot q = 0.5*q*[0, \omega]^T\$

\$\omega = [\omega_x, \omega_y, \omega_z]\$

\$q = [q_r, q_i, q_j, q_k]\$
and then I normalize the output. My solution is:

```
import sympy as sy

def quat_equ(q_l, q_w, renorm=1):
    # quaternion multiplication using equation: q_dot = 0.5 * q * [0, omega)^T
    # multiplication broken up into individual quaternion states
    q_r_d = 0.5 * (q_l[0] * q_w[0] - q_l[1] * q_w[1] + q_l[2] * q_w[2] +
                   q_l[3] * q_w[3])
    q_i_d = 0.5 * (q_l[0] * q_w[1] + q_l[1] * q_w[0] + q_l[2] * q_w[3] -
                   q_l[3] * q_w[2])
    q_j_d = 0.5 * (q_l[0] * q_w[2] + q_l[2] * q_w[0] + q_l[3] * q_w[1] -
                   q_l[1] * q_w[3])
    q_k_d = 0.5 * (q_l[0] * q_w[3] + q_l[3] * q_w[0] + q_l[1] * q_w[2] -
                   q_l[2] * q_w[1])
    # Re-normalizing the quaternion multiple times (heuristic I was taught/required to use)
    # The for loop is causing the slowdown of the code due to re-normalizing 
    for i in range(renorm):
        q_r_d *= 1 / sy.sqrt(q_r_d ** 2 + q_i_d ** 2 + q_j_d ** 2 + q_k_d ** 2)
        q_i_d *= 1 / sy.sqrt(q_r_d ** 2 + q_i_d ** 2 + q_j_d ** 2 + q_k_d ** 2)
        q_j_d *= 1 / sy.sqrt(q_r_d ** 2 + q_i_d ** 2 + q_j_d ** 2 + q_k_d ** 2)
        q_k_d *= 1 / sy.sqrt(q_r_d ** 2 + q_i_d ** 2 + q_j_d ** 2 + q_k_d ** 2)
    return [q_r_d, q_i_d, q_j_d, q_k_d]

# setting up symbolics
q_r, q_i, q_j, q_k, w_ib_l, w_ib_m, w_ib_n = sy.symbols("q_r q_i q_j q_k w_ib_l w_ib_m w_ib_n")
q1 = [q_r, q_i, q_j, q_k]
q2 = [0, w_ib_l, w_ib_m, w_ib_n]

# separation of symbolic equations for each state in q_dot (this is a requirement for the code)
quat0 = quat_equ(q1, q2, 3)[0]
quat1 = quat_equ(q1, q2, 3)[1]
quat2 = quat_equ(q1, q2, 3)[2]
quat3 = quat_equ(q1, q2, 3)[3]

# testing of the symbolic equations using substitution
qq = [1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.]
var = [q_r, q_i, q_j, q_k, w_ib_l, w_ib_m, w_ib_n]

q0 = sy.Subs(quat0, var, qq).doit()
q1 = sy.Subs(quat1, var, qq).doit()
q2 = sy.Subs(quat2, var, qq).doit()
q3 = sy.Subs(quat3, var, qq).doit()
```

When I try to re-normalize the quaternion more than 2 times this method becomes very slow. The symbolic equation also becomes massive because the re-normalization adds on basically 4 extra symbolic equations, which slows down later processes a lot. I couldn't think of a better method to create a normalized quaternion that 1) initializes faster and 2) is a smaller symbolic equation. I don't use symbolics in python much so most of Sympy is new to me.

Comment: Why is `for i in range(1)` written as a loop? It's indentation is wrong, which makes this broken code. (A good way to post code is to paste it into the question editor, highlight it, and press Ctrl-K to mark it as a code block.)

Comment: Note that MathJax is available for writing equations in your question.

Comment: In addition to what 200_success alreay said about broken code, the symbol definition is also no valid Python code. Your code could also greatly benefit from some comments to give reviewers a few hints which parts you suspect or know to be slow.

Comment: Once the code runs without crashing, you should also test it with some simple test cases which will find the obvious bugs it currently has. For preference you could also edit the test code into the question.

Comment: @200_sucess, the for loop is for multiple renormalizations of the quaternion. I had it set to 1 when i copied the code. I want to set the loop to 10.

I'll also make sure to follow suggestions and edit the code. I am new to adding code to stack exchange, so apologize for that.